# Only first field is validated using jquery required validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have this type of multiple dynamic input fields :

```js
$(function() {

    $("form#frmaddclass").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert("form valid");
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            messages: {
                required: "custom select message"
            }
        });

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.2/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/admin/add" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal addclass" id="frmaddclass" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">

    <input class="form-control error" placeholder="Name" id="name" required="" name="name" type="text" value="" aria-invalid="true"><br/>

    <select class="form-control" required="" name="status">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="active">active</option>
        <option value="disabled">inactive</option>
    </select><br/>
    <select class="form-control" required="" name="subject[ETET][]">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="science">science</option>
        <option value="english">english</option>
    </select><br/>
    <select class="form-control" required="" name="subject[ETET][]">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="science">science</option>
        <option value="english">english</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" required="" name="subject[ETET][]">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="science">science</option>
        <option value="english">english</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```
<input type="text" name="subject[b3JxZ][]" class="form-control" aria-invalid="true">
<input type="text" name="subject[bs5xZ][]" class="form-control" aria-invalid="true">
```

but here i don't know the indexes, and i'm using the following code to validate my dynamic input fields but the issue is only the first input field is validated, other fields that are dynamically added are not getting validated.

```
$('.form-control').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", 
        {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "This field is required",
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: your filed name is same?

Comment: please put here your some html code example

Comment: @Paras Raiyani: added html code, please check

Comment: you add new text field after add validation..i check.your code is properly work

Comment: @Paras Raiyani,but on myside newly created text fields are not validated

Comment: please put here your full html code and js code

Comment: so i want to check

Comment: @Paras Raiyani: I have added code, but there is one issue my array keys are same, is there any way to validate this because in my case i have to give same keys,

Comment: @ParasRaiyani: Can i validate all fields starting with subject

Comment: As explained in your other question, you have duplicate names, which are not allowed.  When you use the same name more than once, only the first instance is validated and the others are ignored.  This is just how the plugin works and there are no workarounds or tricks.